# Is it common practice to combine Bootstrap with other frameworks?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Is it common practice to combine Bootstrap with other frameworks?

For example React.
My perception some-why is that Bootstrap is solving responsiveness and than other frameworks are installed on top of it e.g. React. Is this true?

Comment: "Framework" can be a very ambiguous word. But think of this -- Bootstrap from the beginning required jQuery in order to work. React completely replaces the need for jQuery, but doesn't intersect at all with Bootstrap. So Bootstrap + React is the same thing as Bootstrap + jQuery

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Bootstrap and React are two different worlds!

React is a library for building user interfaces.
Bootstrap is a toolkit.

Yes, you can combine it (If you use [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)). But you can't combine the "original" Bootstrap with React. Because React removes the need to use jQuery.

What you can't combine (in the same project) I think is for example: Angular and React, or React and Vue.JS.

So, with React you build the "foundation" of your project and with Bootstrap you create your UI.

Comment: `But you can't combine the "original" Bootstrap with React.` This is  false

Comment: So please contribute your idea to [CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-bootstrap/)

Comment: You can use the original Bootstrap styling without jQuery, only an optional subset of components needs JavaScript to be fully dynamic in Bootstrap.

Comment: Also, you can combine Angular and React and Vue.js, it's not a good idea from the start, but it's possible, e.g. if you need to transition from one to the other.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi, that's not the original Bootstrap, that's only the CSS part.

Comment: @EmileBergeron agreed, if you're transitioning from one to other is possible, but not recommended to start a project with both together